# RealmファイルのデータをCSV形式でインポート、エクスポート

Tags: realm

RealmファイルのデータをCSV出力、読み込みできないかなと模索してます。
サーバからCSV形式で置いて、ユーザごとにデータを読ませて復元したいのですが、
そのような機能はありますでしょうか。RealmブラウザにもCSV出力、入力機能があると
非常にありがたい。標準機能としてないのであればその代替え手段ないでしょうか。

Answer (score 1):

Realm BrowserはデータのCSVエクスポート、およびCSVまたはEXCELファイルによるインポート機能があります。FileメニューのImport、Exportをご覧ください。また https://github.com/realm/realm-cocoa-converter というある程度柔軟なデータ構造のマッピングに対応したツールもサポートしています。

ただ、CSVはデータ型が規定されているわけではありませんので、Realmのデータスキーマへのマッピングは自明ではないので、たいていはアプリケーションで調整することになります。CSVを読み込んでRealmに保存する処理は別に難しいものではないので、最初からアプリケーションにあったやり方で書いた方が早いのではないかと思います。

Comment: ＞Realm Browse
すいません、そんな機能あったのですね。見落としてました。
csvは型の情報がないので全部Stringとして扱われるわけですね。データは他のDBから移行されるものなのでCSVを避けて通れません。上記の方法検討して見ます。いつもありがとうございます。

Comment: はい。CSVを使ってデータを移行するのは一般的だと思います。その場合、CSVはデータ構造としては大抵のDBよりは単純なのと、スキーマとのマッピングが必要になります。そしてそれはアプリケーションの要件によるところが大きいので、既存のものはありますが、それを使うよりは自分で書いたほうがほとんどの場合は良いと思います。